# How can I turn the entire div into a clickable link?

Tags: html, css

Here's my code: 
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Squallz Test Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>This is a header</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Repo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Code</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="footerinfo">
        <p id="copyright">Copyright © Squallz 2017 - Rights Reserved</p>
        <p id="info">Personal website by <b>Squallz</b></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: url("../images/bg.png") no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

header {
  background-color: #088CAF;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.navigation {
  position: sticky;
}

.navigation ul {
  background-color: #075E75;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #2E2E2E;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #2E2E2E;
}

.navigation ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

.navigation li:hover {
  background-color: #069DAA;
}

.navigation ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.footer {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2E2E2E;
  border-top: 2px solid #099C9E;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -800px;
  height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I just want it to where when I highlight the li with a link in it, the entire thing will be clickable. I know that I could make them all individual divs wrapped by anchors but that's messy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your `a` tag full width and height of the li. Moving `padding:20px;` to your `a` tag css and adding `display:block;` allows the links to be clickable, without modifying your HTML.

Update your `li` tag css to:

```
.navigation ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Update your `a` tag css to:

```
.navigation ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  display:block;
}
```

**Full Code:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: url("../images/bg.png") no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

header {
  background-color: #088CAF;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.navigation {
  position: sticky;
}

.navigation ul {
  background-color: #075E75;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #2E2E2E;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #2E2E2E;
}

.navigation ul li {
  display: inline-block;  
}

.navigation li:hover {
  background-color: #069DAA;
}

.navigation ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  display:block;
}

.footer {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2E2E2E;
  border-top: 2px solid #099C9E;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -800px;
  height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Squallz Test Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>This is a header</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Repo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Code</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="footerinfo">
        <p id="copyright">Copyright © Squallz 2017 - Rights Reserved</p>
        <p id="info">Personal website by <b>Squallz</b></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I'm new to HTML and CSS. I've completed a full course on Codeacademy but I think the best way is to be taught directly. Do you by chance have some time to teach me a little bit? :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply interchange `<li>` to `<a>` like:

`<a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>`

Then just change this in your css to retain the design

```
.navigation ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. Why do you need to modify the html structure?

Answer (score 0):

Take the padding off your `li` and set the anchor within to `display: block` with its own padding.

`.navigation li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
}`

The only real concern is that the targets may be too close together, which you can solve with slightly larger margins between each list item.

Answer (score 0):

Simple add to `.navigation ul li a`

```
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
```

And remove it from `.navigation ul li`

```
padding: 20px;
```

Full code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: url("../images/bg.png") no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

header {
  background-color: #088CAF;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.navigation {
  position: sticky;
}

.navigation ul {
  background-color: #075E75;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #2E2E2E;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #2E2E2E;
}

.navigation ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navigation li:hover {
  background-color: #069DAA;
}

.navigation ul li a {
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.footer {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2E2E2E;
  border-top: 2px solid #099C9E;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -800px;
  height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>This is a header</h1>
</header>
<div class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Repo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Code</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footerinfo">
    <p id="copyright">Copyright © Squallz 2017 - Rights Reserved</p>
    <p id="info">Personal website by <b>Squallz</b></p>
  </div>
</div>
```